# How to group radio box buttons using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a program with grouped check box and get confused on how the messages convey through different handles.

IDE:VC++, Win32 API

First, I have a main window which has a handle, say **hWnd**.

And in the WndProc function under case WM_CREATE, we create the "group button" and the individual 2 check boxes

Note: the first button uses "BS_GROUPBOX" style, and it was created with the handle **hGrpButton** while its parent handler is **hWnd**. The second and third button is "BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON" style and it's parent handle is **hGrpButton**.

If the 2 buttons are not grouped(so their parent hanlder would be hWnd), it is easy to check the status of them. Just simply go to case WM_COMMAND AND use their ID to check with the IsDlgButtonChecked function. After the two check boxes are grouped (their parent handle are not longer hWnd but hGrpButtons), I don't think the case WM_COMMAND will find their IDs since it is looking for the IDs under hWnd.

In short, after 2 check boxes are grouped, I don't know what is the event to monitor them.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{        
/*Group for Radio button for preview/single or batch operation */
hGrpButtons=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"Select Process Mode:", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_GROUPBOX,  // Styles 
                    10,280,
                    350,100, 
                    hWnd, 
                    NULL, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"Batch Process Mode", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
                    10,20,
                    300,20, 
                    hGrpButtons, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK1, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"Single Process Mode (Preview Mode)", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
                    10,45,
                    300,20, 
                    hGrpButtons, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK2, 
                    hInst, NULL);
```

Comment: The group box does not functionally "group" the controls within. It is for visual clarity only. To receive the messages from the radio buttons you must use the parent hWnd as their parent window.

Answer (score 21):

After read Coder_Dan's comment and MSDN article "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775947(v=vs.85).aspx#related_topics" about the button types, I finally sort it out.

1. BS_GROUPBOX is just an "eye candy" and it did no contribute to the group of the radio box!! The critical parameter to control the grouping is the "WS_GROUP"
2. How to group the radio box: Put the WS_GROUP in the first radio button's style. It will group the current radio button until it see the second WS_GROUP as mentioned by Coder_Dan.

Modification on my previous code

a. use hWnd as parent for all 4 radio buttons

b. Put WS_GROUP in the first and third button style so that we group the 1,2 and 3,4 radio buttons

c. Now you can go to the WM_COMMAND, and listen to the messages from the 4 buttons according to their IDs under the main window's handle hWnd

```
    case WM_CREATE:
{        

/*Group for Radio button for preview/single or batch operation */
hGrpButtons=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"Select Process Mode:", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_GROUPBOX,// <----BS_GROUPBOX does nothing on the grouping 
                    10,280,
                    350,100, 
                    hWnd, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_GRPBUTTONS, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"first radio button", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON|WS_GROUP,  // <---- WS_GROUP group the following radio buttons 1st,2nd button 
                    10,520,
                    300,20, 
                    hWnd, //<----- Use main window handle
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK1, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"second radio button", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
                    10,545,
                    300,20, 
                    hWnd, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK2, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"third radio button", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTOCHECKBOX|WS_GROUP,  //<---Start second group for 3rd,4th button
                    10,570,
                    300,20, 
                    hWnd, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK3, 
                    hInst, NULL);
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    L"BUTTON",
                    L"forth radio button", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
                    500,545,
                    300,20, 
                    hWnd, 
                    (HMENU)IDC_CHK4, 
                    hInst, NULL);
```